# How to modify the tensorflow loss function to suit multi labels on the same image

Tags: tensorflow

Tensorflow is fairly new to me and the way i would have the loss calculated on the mnist dataset was using the softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits function.
This function worked on that dataset due to the label input being a single label on each image
What im trying to do is to train a CNN on the mscoco dataset which has multiple labels on the same image with 80 classes total.
Is there a function that makes that possible?
My label input is currently somewhat a modified onehot representation, meaning that for each image i have a list of 80 elements having 0 for categories not in the image and 1 for categories present in an image
I.e. an image with a human and a dog would have a list of [0,1,0,0,1] assuming i have 5 classes with dogs and humans being in index 1 and 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multi-label classification problem, you can use the sigmoid function available in tensorflow ([tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits)). It would take the onehot encoded label input along with the final logits layer as its input.

Comment: Thank you ill try it and get back to you. However, the accuracy was also being calculated by comparing the highest output class from the highest score of softmax over logits and the highest value from original labels..how would it be calculated in multilabel form.